# React JS , jQuery TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs

I'm using ES6 React JS .

I used npm to install jquery , but when I run below code getting error. Could anyone help ?

> TypeError: undefined is not a function
>
> at loadDataFromServer (path/Utils.js:9:6)

```
import $ from 'jquery';

function loadDataFromServer(callBackSuccess , callBackError){
  console.log($);
  var url = "http://localhost:9000/api/json";

   $.ajax({
     url: url,
     dataType: 'json',
     cache: false,
     success: function(data) {
       callBackSuccess(data);
     },
     error: function(xhr, status, err) {
       callBackError(err);
     }
   });
}



export { loadDataFromServer }
```